# How to get media content in base64 fromat usnig Goutte Client for BotDetectCaptcha

Tags: php, web-scraping, base64, goutte, botdetect

I am writing a scraper for office task:
My Goutte Client code is like:

```
$cokie = "JSESSIONID=0000H_WHw_eFPKVUDGxUei7v3PH:1db7cfi4s";
$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
        'Host' => 'verification.nadra.gov.pk',
        "Cookie" => $cokie,
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0'
    ),
)));
$cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", $cokie, null, "/service", "https://example.com/", true, true);
$client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
$client->setServerParameter('HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0');
$client->followRedirects(true);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&amp;c=exampleCaptcha&amp;t=508c5eaf74fd4858b0c9debafc319d67');
```

I have to send request with cookie to get the proper content.

```
https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&amp;c=exampleCaptcha&amp;t=508c5eaf74fd4858b0c9debafc319d67
```

Result is again same url:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>botdetectcaptcha (JPEG Image, 250&nbsp;×&nbsp;40 pixels)</title></head>
<body><img
        src="https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&amp;c=exampleCaptcha&amp;t=508c5eaf74fd4858b0c9debafc319d67"
        alt="https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&amp;c=exampleCaptcha&amp;t=508c5eaf74fd4858b0c9debafc319d67">
</body>
</html>
```

in browser it is working fine but the issue is when I get the image from this url it again generate new image without cookie that is way it is not working.

I have tried the below:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents("https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&amp;c=exampleCaptcha&amp;t=508c5eaf74fd4858b0c9debafc319d67"));
```

above send the GET request without cookie that is way received image does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done using file_get_contents by sending same client information as I am sending in Goutte Client

```
$url = "https://example.com/service/botdetectcaptcha?get=image&c=exampleCaptcha&t=9d15db63ddc449f1850aad6e3183ce2e";

$options = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
"Cookie: " . $cookie_value ."\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
"Host: https://example.com/\r\n" .
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0\r\n" // i.e. An iPad
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$img_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
file_put_contents('img/img_9d15db63ddc449f1850aad6e3183ce2e.png', base64_decode($img_base64));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML and Image are served from same URL you need to define `Accept` header and in your first example you expect `text/html’, if you want to get an image you need to send` image/png` see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values

Comment: Thanks! I tried but the issue did not resolve. so I tried as I answer below. your solution works when url have image. in my case it was something different.